# Find absolute path in linux using strchr

Tags: c, linux, path, strchr

How can we use the function `strchr` to find absolute path in linux, for example:

```
Input: /home/test/sample
Output: /home/test
```

I try to write something like this:

```
int main() {
char* string = "/home/test/sample";
char* pos;
pos = strchr(string, '/');
printf("%s\n", pos);
return 0;
}
```

But that's not working, I got the same output as the input:

```
Input: /home/test/sample
Output: /home/test/sample
```

Comment: Quote from the manual page: *The strchr() function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character c in the string s.* This first occurrence is the left most, which is the first character.

Comment: You are using the wrong terminology.  Technically what you are looking for is the pathname prefix.

Comment: From the code sample, it appears that you do not actually want the absolute path.  If you do want the absolute path, try `realpath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [dirname](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) function instead:

```
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char* string = strdup ("/home/test/sample");
  char* pos;
  pos = dirname (string);
  printf ("%s\n", pos);
  return 0;
}
```

In order to search for the right most occurrence use the [strrchr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strrchr.3.html) function.